# Find if date is within 14 days if id matches between datasets in R

Tags: r

I have 2 datasets as follows:

```
id<-c(5,8,11,11,13,14)
date<-c("2001-1-1","2002-2-2","2003-3-3","2003-6-3","2004-4-4","2005-5-5")
data<-data.frame(cbind(id,date))

id<-c(1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,7,8,9,10,10,11,11,12,13)
date<-c("2001-1-2","2002-1-1","2002-3-3","2002-4-15","1999-10-12","2002-12-25","2008-4-9","2005-2-6","2004-5-14","2004-10-30","2011-4-25","2013-12-10","2014-1-1","2001-1-1","2003-2-26","2003-3-2","2010-10-10","2004-4-4")
ns<-data.frame(cbind(id,date))
```

Note that only some of the id in data are included in ns and viceversa.

I am trying to find for each of the values in data$id if there is a na$date that is 14 days before the `data$date` where `data$id==ns$id`.

This is what I wrote, but is there a faster way (it is taking a long time now as I have thousands of entries in each dataset), and besides I don’t think it is working either.

```
 data$episode<-c(1:length(data$id))
 ns$episode<-c(1:length(ns$id))
 data$date<-as.Date(data$date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
 ns$date<-as.Date(ns$date,format="%Y-%m-%d")
 z<-0
 for(i in data$episode){
   for(j in ns$episode){
     z=z+1
     received[z]<-ifelse(data$id[i]==ns$id[j],
                      ifelse(as.numeric(data$date[i]-ns$date[j])<14,1,0),
                      NA)
   }
 }
 received<-received[!is.na(received)]
```

The output I need is a vector of the same length of data$episode, with a 1 if the date in `ns$date[ns$id==data$id]` is less than 14 days before the respective `data$date`.
I hope this makes sense.

Comment: `id` and `date` for `ns`have different lengths (17 vs 18)  and `data.frame(id,date)` should do, `cbind` is unnecessary as it converts all columns to common format, character in this case

Comment: @Osssan sorry I had noticed it after I posted and corrected it within few minutes (it should work know). Thanks for the cbind tip, but still it does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I used `lubridate` to convert the dates.

```
library(lubridate)

# convert dates
data$date <- ymd(data$date)
ns$date <- ymd(ns$date)

# left join datasets
tmp <- merge(data, ns, by="id", all.x=TRUE)

# create variable for less than 14 days
tmp$received <- with(tmp, abs(difftime(date.x, date.y, units="days")) < 14)

# check each id and date combination for TRUE
tmp <- aggregate(received ~ id + date.x, tmp, any)
names(tmp) <- c("id", "date", "received")

# merge back into data to capture missing groups
tmp <- merge(data, tmp, by=c("id", "date"), all.x=TRUE)
```

I did a left join because you wanted the new vector to have the same length as `data`. That said, there is one `NA` value (using your example data) since there is one `id` in `data` that is not in `ns`.

Using the example data:

```
> tmp
  id       date received
1 11 2003-03-03     TRUE
2 11 2003-06-03    FALSE
3 13 2004-04-04     TRUE
4 14 2005-05-05       NA
5  5 2001-01-01     TRUE
6  8 2002-02-02    FALSE
```