# Combination of merge and aggregate in R

Tags: r

I have created the following 2 dummy datasets as follows:

```
id<-c(8,8,50,87,141,161,192,216,257,282)
date<-c("2011-03-03","2011-12-12","2010-08-18","2009-04-28","2010-11-29","2012-04-02","2013-01-08","2007-01-22","2009-06-03","2009-12-02")
data<-data.frame(cbind(id,date))

id<-c(3,8,11,11,11,11,11,11,19,19,19,19,19,50,50,50,50,50,87,87,87,87,87,87,282,282,282,282,282,282,282,282,282,282,288,288,288,288,288,288,288,288,288,288,288,288,288)
date<-c("2010-11-04","2011-02-25","2009-07-26","2009-07-27","2009-08-09","2009-08-10","2009-08-30","2004-01-20","2006-02-13","2006-07-18","2007-04-20","2008-05-12","2008-05-29","2009-06-10","2010-08-17","2010-08-15","2011-05-13","2011-06-08","2007-08-09","2008-01-19","2008-02-19","2009-04-28","2009-05-16","2009-05-20","2005-05-14","2007-04-15","2007-07-25","2007-10-12","2007-10-23","2007-10-27","2007-11-20","2009-11-28","2012-08-16","2012-08-16","2008-11-17","2009-10-23","2009-10-27","2009-10-27","2009-10-27","2009-10-27","2009-10-28","2010-06-15","2010-06-17","2010-06-23","2010-07-27","2010-07-27","2010-07-28")
ns<-data.frame(cbind(id,date))
```

Note that only some of the id in data are included in ns and viceversa.

For each of the values in data$id I am trying to find if there is a ns$date that is 14 days before the data$date where data$id==ns$id and report the number of days difference.

The output I need is a vector/column ("received") of the same number of rows of data, with a TRUE/FALSE whre ns$date[ns$id==data$id] is less than 14 days before the respective data$date and a similar vector with the actual number of days where "received" is TRUE. I hope this makes sense now.

This is where I got so far

```
# convert dates
data$date <- ymd(data$date)
ns$date <- ymd(ns$date)

# left join datasets
tmp <- merge(data, ns, by="id", all.x=TRUE)
#NOTE THAT this will automatically rename data$date as date.x and  tmp$date as date.y

# create variable to say when there is a date difference less than 14 days
tmp$received <- with(tmp, difftime(date.x, date.y, units="days")<14&difftime(date.x, date.y, units="days")>0)
#create a variable that reports the days difference
tmp$dif<-ifelse(tmp$received==TRUE,difftime(tmp$date.x,tmp$date.y, units="days"),NA)
```

This link [Find if date is within 14 days if id matches between datasets in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369371/find-if-date-is-within-14-days-if-id-matches-between-datasets-in-r) provides an idea but the result does not include the number of days difference in tmp$dif.

In the result table I need only the lowest difference for each data$id for those cases were tmp$received was TRUE.

Hope this makes more sense now? If not please let me know what needs further clarification.
M

PS: as requested I added what the desired output should look like (same number of rows of data = 10 - no rows for data in ns not in data). Should have thought this might help earlier.

```
   id         date   received     dif
1   8   2011-03-03       TRUE       6
2   8   2011-12-12      FALSE      NA
3   50  2010-08-18       TRUE       1
4   87  2009-04-28       TRUE       0
5   141 2010-11-29         NA      NA
6   161 2012-04-02         NA      NA
7   192 2013-01-08         NA      NA
8   216 2007-01-22         NA      NA
9   257 2009-06-03         NA      NA
10  282 2009-12-02       TRUE       4
```

Comment: Your code is not reproducible (there is no column `date.x` in `tmp` as you already renamed it and there is no column `date.y` at all) and it is unclear what you asking

Comment: Thank you @DavidArenburg I had put a link to the previous question this was developed from. As this was not clear I also paste here the relevant data. The columns date.x and date.y originate automatically when running the first merge command. Hope this helps

Comment: I saw the link to your original question, but this line `names(tmp) <- c("id", "date", "received")` overrides `date.x` and the previous line removes `date.y`

Comment: @DavidArenburg this code was the answer from the previous question and it does what I meant it to do. The names(tmp) changes the names to be able to merge data with tmp in the end. As far as I understand the previous line (the aggregate line) keeps those results where there is a TRUE for each date.x (then renamed "date") and when no true is available is keeps a FALSE. The date.y is lost there because there are multiple date.y and since they are aggregated  it can not keep them. And I am not interested in the date.y in the result. I am just asking if it is possible to keep a column ->

Comment: -> through the aggregate command. So that when there is a TRUE in tmp$received it also attaches the correspondent value in tmp$dif. When tmp$received is FALSE I am happy wiht a NA. Does this make sense?

Comment: If you only interested in a specific case, erase all the code above, provide some dummy data set, and the desired output. As it stands now, your question is a big mess with not reproducible code and lots of unneeded information which makes it very frustrating to try to help you

Comment: Ok, my apologies. I thought there would be a quick fix in the tmp<-aggregate(...) to do this; obviously this is not the case then. I will do as you suggest. Cheers

Comment: I guess the fix will be quick. The problem is not the fix but trying to understand what is your data and what is the desired output in this mess. Anyways, it is preferable to use `dplyr` or `data.table` instead of `aggregate` as both more efficient and more flexible

Comment: @DavidArenburg is this any clearer?

Comment: It is better, just add how the desired output should look like

Comment: You haven't provided desired output so I went ahead and posted an answer. If it not exactly what you want. I'm sure it can be edited easily

Comment: Many thanks @DavidArenburg for your help, but as requested I added what the desired output should look like (same number of rows of data and only the smaller timediff where applicable between data$date and ns$date; no rows !ns$id%in%data$id,). Should have thought sooner this might help too, apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `data.table` approach

Converting to `data.table` objects

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(data), id) 
setkey(setDT(ns), id)
```

Merging

```
ns <- ns[data]
```

Converting to `Date` class

```
ns[, c("date", "date.1") := lapply(.SD, as.Date), .SDcols = c("date", "date.1")]
```

Computing days differences and `TRUE`/`FALSE`

```
ns[, `:=`(timediff = date.1 - date,
          Logical = (date.1 - date) < 14)]
```

Taking only the rows we are interested in

```
res <- ns[is.na(timediff) | timediff >= 0, list(received = any(Logical), dif = timediff[Logical]), by = list(id, date.1)]
```

Sorting by `id` and `date`

```
res[, id := as.numeric(as.character(id))]
setkey(res, id, date.1)
```

Subsetting by minimum dstance

```
res[, list(diff = min(dif)), by = list(id, date.1, received)]

#      id     date.1 received    diff
#  1:   8 2011-03-03     TRUE  6 days
#  2:   8 2011-12-12    FALSE NA days
#  3:  50 2010-08-18     TRUE  1 days
#  4:  87 2009-04-28     TRUE  0 days
#  5: 141 2010-11-29       NA NA days
#  6: 161 2012-04-02       NA NA days
#  7: 192 2013-01-08       NA NA days
#  8: 216 2007-01-22       NA NA days
#  9: 257 2009-06-03       NA NA days
# 10: 282 2009-12-02     TRUE  4 days
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks promising. For those records in "ns" were two records with less than 14 days difference I need to keep only the one with the smallest difference.